# How to convert the path of an file created on android to save it on iOS and vice versa

Tags: flutter

In order to send files between 2 clients (android/iOS devices) with an nodejs server, iam converting files to base64 and decode them.

But iam facing the problem that android and iOS has different application directory paths.

File path on android: /storage/emulated/0/projectName/media/photos/username/20230420-214001-131-043.jpg

File path on iOS: '/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E96EF626-6063-4B74-B430-5F3FF73FD1B9/data/Containers/Data/Application/269EED59-275B-447F-8F82-B82D85723D3F/Documents/media/photos/username/20230420-214001-131-043.jpg'

This code throws an error, that the file or directory does not exists

```
Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(filePathAsBase64);
File decodedimgfile = await File('${appDocDirFolder.path}test.jpg').writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

So in order to save the file from android to iOS i have to modify the filepath, but i don`t know how?

Thank you!